# Excel - From a list, find the next value higher than 0

Tags: excel

Assuming that I have the next list:

[image]

How can I formulate a cell "result", that searches for T1 in the list, but returns the value of (Column C) that matches the first (T1 in column A) where value in (column B) is higher than 0. Example, if I look for T1, It should return 9. Neither 10 nor 8.

Comment: Easy! Put your data in a proper RDBMS (even ACCESS) and use SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will find the next one after the 0:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(E2,IF(B:B>0,A:A),0))
```

It is an array formula confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that's exactly what I needed

Comment: @EricK. I get taught stuff daily here.  In fact just got taught something on another tread by jeeped.

Answer (score 1):

sumifs(C:C,A:A,E2,B:B,">0")

Put this formula in result (F2)

Comment: This will sum the results if there are multiple T1s where B is not 0.  He specifically said he wants the first not a sum of all.

Comment: Thanks Eric, Scott is right, I don't want to sum them up. I only need the first value